# Number of pairs with sum $m^2$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $a$ and $b$ are chosen at random from $S = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then the number of pairs $(a, b)$ with sum $m^2$ is $m^2-1$ for $m^2\leq n$, and $2n-m^2+1$ for $n<m^2\leq 2n$.

I can easily understand the first part of the second statement but not the 2nd part. Can anyone explain how are we getting this?

For $n<m^2\leq 2n$ there are $m^2-1$ pairs which give sum $m^2$ but out of these pairs there are some of them whose entries do not belong to the set $S$. So, we have to remove those pairs. But I don't know how many of them are there in general. I tried with some examples but in vain.

Thanks!

Comment: Count the pairs in $\{(m^2-n, n), (m^2-n+1, n-1), (m^2-n+2, n-2), ..., (n, m^2-n)\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $s\in S$ let $s'=n+1-s$; the map $S\to S:s\mapsto s'$ is an involution. For $a,b\in S$ we have $a+b=m^2$ if and only if $a'+b'=2n-m^2+2$.

Now assume that $n<m^2\le 2n$; then $2\le 2n-m^2+2\le n+1$, so that if $c+d=2n-m^2+2$ for positive integers $c$ and $d$, then $c,d\in S$. There are $2n-m^2+1$ ordered pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ of positive integers whose sum is $2n-m^2+2$. Let $\langle a,b\rangle$ be such a pair; then $\langle a,b\rangle\in S\times S$, so $\langle a',b'\rangle\in S\times S$, and $a'+b'=m^2$. Thus, there are $2n-m^2+1$ pairs $\langle a,b\rangle\in S\times S$ such that $a+b=m^2$.

Comment: How are you getting this? - For $a,b\in S$ we have $a+b=m$ if and only if $a'+b'=2n-m^2+2$. If I try to prove the only if case I am getting, $a'+b'=(n+1-a)+(n+1-b)=2n+2-(a+b)=2n+2-m$ as $a+b=m$. I think there is a typo in there, $a+b$ should be $m^2$, right?

Comment: @uuuuuuuuuu: Yes, it should; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $1\leq a,b\leq n$ and $m^2\leq 2n$ then
$$n\geq \max(a,b)\geq \frac{a+b}{2}\geq \frac{m^2}{2}$$
is always satisfied. Therefore for any $a\in \{m^2-n,\dots,n\}$  (note that $m^2-n\geq 1$ because $m^2>n$), we have a proper couple $(a,m^2-a)$. Finally observe that the cardinality of the set of values for $a$, that is $\{m^2-n,\dots,n\}$ is just
$$n-(m^2-n)+1=2n-m^2+1.$$